# Programming controls outside of the main loop in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

What I'm trying to do is define controls for a certain thing in another module which defines everything else for that thing, then run the controls from the main loop via a function.

The problem with trying to call it with a function, from what I've tried, is that the events that the function sees only match the events when the function was defined at the program start instead of the current events; meaning, no events.

Here's an example of what I mean:

*main file*

```
from pygameinitmodule import *
import othermodule

#event_list = pygame.event.get() is run in pygameinitmodule to define it for all modules

running = True
while running:
    #updating the event_list
    event_list = pygame.event.get()

    if certaingamestate:
        othermodule.controlFunction()
```

*othermodule*

```
from pygameinitmodule import *

def controlFunction():
    global event_list
    for event in event_list:
        # controls here
```

And if I am then to run the code, the controls don't work. But if I put the exact same code from the function into the main loop it works fine. Is there another way I'm supposed to do something like this, or am I doing it mostly right while overlooking one critical part?

Edit: to the person that marked this as a duplicate, it's not. The question you marked this as a duplicate of is focusing on a different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the event list as an argument to the function:

*other_module.py*

```py
def controlFunction(event_list):
    for event in event_list:
        # do stuff
```

And in the main loop use as such:

*main_file.py*

```py
while True:
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    controlFunction(event_list)
```

---

Or just `import pygame` in the other file and get the events there (this approach, however, is not suggested since it removes events from the queue and they can't be retrieved from other places):

*other_module.py*

```py
import pygame

def controlFunction():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # do stuff
```